# How to lock navigation and tab bars?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

So currently I'm making a news app for iPhone, and I want to create a custom navigation and tab bars for it. So I switched off my standard navigation bar and toolbar in Navigation Controller to add new custom ones.
But the problem is that after I add this bars to my TableView where the RSS feed is displayed and trying to scroll it up and down my bars move along with feed.

Is there any option to lock my bars on top and bottom of the screen respectively? So I can scroll feed in between them?
Sorry, was not sure what kind of information I need to provide, my bad. Here is how my tableView looks like, where the feed is displayed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5AiP.jpg

Here is the code, where I add an image to my navigation bar:

let navBgImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "123.png")!
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBgImage, forBarMetrics: .Default)

Here is an example of how it works:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVsb3.png

As you can see the navigation bar moves along with feed and leaves the screen, so there is no error. I'm just trying to figure out how can I lock the bar on top of the screen so it will stay there even when I scroll the feed. Same goes for the tab bar.

Comment: It is impossible to know what's going on without more context.  Can you provide some code, and tell us exactly where the error is occurring?

Comment: Sorry, was not sure what kind of information I need to provide, my bad. Here is how my tableView looks like, where the feed is displayed: http://imgur.com/qLXuBfn 

Here is the code, where I add an image to my navigation bar:

let navBgImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "123.png")!
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBgImage, forBarMetrics: .Default) 

Here is an example of how it works:  http://imgur.com/14Ifh8t,9wMn8gs

As you can see the navigation bar moves along with feed and leaves the screen, so there is no error. I'm just trying to figure out how can I lock bar.

Comment: @JAL added a comment to a main topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your navigation and tool bars to the view containing your table view, not to the table view itself. In IB, I would temporarily remove the table view, add your bars, and make sure they are pinned to the top and bottom of the veiw, and then put your table view back in, setting the size to fit between the top and bottom bar.